# Cannot create folder and file on external drive (Xfce, Thunar) after change of mount point

Tags: partitioning, mount, hard-drive, ntfs, external-hdd

I wanted to have an ntfs partition mounted at startup, so I used [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/260527/47206) solution to mount it automatically. (Using a program to set the automatic mounting: "Storage Device Manager" - `pysdm`.)

At a certain point I wanted this for an external drive (fat32) that is most of the time connected to the computer, which was not usually mounted when the computer started.

All went well until I noticed that in Thunar it was not possible to create new folder (or file) - the option was greyed out - on the external drive (while on the ntfs partition all was well):

[image]

I have also noticed that the use of the  "Storage Device Manager" in the way presented by the linked answer had changed the mount point of the drives involved: before, external drive's point had been `/media/cipricus/SAMSUNG/`, now it is `/media/sdb1/`; the ntfs drive had the mount point `/media/cipricus/3060-0887/` and now it is `/media/sda5/`. (But, as specified, there is no problem with the ntfs partition.)

Uninstalling the program and trying to go back to the older situation didn't work, the partition and the external drive continued to mount at the new mount points.

---

UPDATE: I was able to revert to the old mount points by using the same program, but this did not solve the issue with the external drive. Even worse, I had to un-check the options for mounting at boot for both drives involved for the boot was stopped with an error message that mounting them was not possible.

---

**What I want  is to find a way to go back to the situation from before installing the program and making those settings in the first place.**

---

(A second external drive, for which I didn't used "Storage Device Manager" to make it mount at startup, keeps mounting the usual way, `/media/cipricus/USB-HDD/`, and I can create folders on that one.)

Comment: yes because you don't have any access to the new location where the drive is mounted. In short you have to use `chown` and `chmod` commands to get the privileges to work on that location.

Comment: If you open a terminal and do `touch /media/sdb1/test_user` what do you get? What do you get if you do `sudo touch /media/sdb1/test_root`? What is the output of `mount|grep ' /media/sdb1 '|cut -d'(' -f2`?

Comment: @cipricus Ok!! First it is very important to know where is your disk mounted and what mount access permission it is using? So please provide the result of this command: `mount`

Comment: @SauravKumar - the mountpoint for the external HDD (unlike the internal) is the old one now but still cannot create folders. `mount` gives [this](http://pastebin.com/X5igm1Tt)

Comment: @cipricus: pretty strange! so your new mount point for `sdb1` is `/media/sdb1` as you described in your post.. right?

Comment: @cipricus: Check my answer..

Comment: @cipricus can you go to [chat]?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, try to not use anymore PySDM sience this application is deprecated [starting with Ubuntu 12.10 and higher](https://askubuntu.com/questions/231880/pysdm-missing-in-ubuntu-12-10-and-higher). Futhermore, starting with Ubuntu 12.10, [the default mount points was moved to `/media/$USER`](https://askubuntu.com/questions/214646/how-to-configure-the-default-automount-location) and from here your problems which collide head with PySDM.

So, instead to use anymore PySDM, I suggest you to use [AriOS Automount (.deb)](http://sourceforge.net/projects/arios/files/repo/arios-automount-1.0_all.deb/download) (see [here](https://askubuntu.com/q/40779/147044) how to install a ".deb" file):

> AriOS Automount is a small utility [...] and its main advantage over
>   PySDM is that it doesn't require any kind of configuration: just
>   install it and you're done, all your partitions (it should work with
>   any kind of partition: EXT4/3/2, NTFS, FAT and so on) will be
>   automatically mounted the next time you log in.
>
> AriOS Automount works without touching `/etc/fstab` and it can be
>   enabled / disabled either from the Startup Applications or via the
>   menu, by launching "Auto-mount Settings".

Source: [How To Mount Partitions Automatically On Startup In Linux ~ Ubuntu / Linux blog](http://www.webupd8.org/2011/11/how-to-mount-partitions-automatically.html).

In Xfce "Auto-mount Settings" appears under Menu/System

[image]

And can be enabled/disabled easily

[image]

---

If I have not convinced you and you sill want to use PySDM, try to change the mount point to `/media/$user/devicename` (`/media/cipricus/SAMSUNG`, respectively `/media/cipricus/3060-0887/`):

[image: PySDM]

And:

[image: PySDM]

Comment: indeed the second option you mention (cipricus as owner user) allows creating files and folders

Comment: after making that setting, but also unchecking 'The file system is mounted at boot time', and then uninstalling pysdm, the **initial** situation is in place: which is what my question finally asks. maybe i will test the Arios staff in the future.

Comment: AriOS Automount works as intended and without the problems that I encountered when trying to make a similar setting with other apps. i have edited to add images

Answer (score 1):

Changing the ownership and permission may help you to access your drive.

These steps would help you to do so.

- First un-mount your `/dev/sdb1` drive

  ```
  sudo umount /dev/sdb1
  ```
- And then change the ownership of `/media/sdb1` to working user.

  ```
  sudo chown -R cipricus:cipricus /media/sdb1
  ```

  if `cipricus` is your Ubuntu user's name (if this command fails says: `directory not found` then ignore previous step i,e un-mounting)
- Then change the access permission

  ```
  sudo chmod -R 774 /media/sdb1
  ```
- And last `mount` the driver again.

  ```
  sudo mount -a
  ```

  if it doesn't mount then try to mount from `icon` from your `home folder` or from `gparted`.

Reply what happens..

Comment: I ask those who press thumb down to give reasons! What wrong you found in this! This is fully verified by me and working great!! If you need further assistance just reply and tell me the problem you got! This is quite a suggestion that would be modified according to the scenarios..

Comment: as i had already changed the mountpoint with that program, i have tested your commands replacing `/media/sdb1` with `/media/cipricus/SAMSUNG/` but that did not work (could not create folders). so, i changed the mount point of the hdd with Storage Device Manager to `/media/sdb1` but still no luck after firing those commands. maybe i should restart. in Storage Device Manager i had un-checked 'The filesystem is mounted at boot time' because had experienced problems at boot

Comment: no luck. tested the commands with both mount points (/media/sdb1 and /media/cipricus/SAMSUNG/ - as i can edit those with Storage Device Manager). but still those options are greyed out in both cases

Comment: @SauravKumar What's the point to use `sudo ch... blablabla /media/sdb1` since there is nothing after `sudo umount /dev/sdb1`? Because of this I suspect your downvote... I abstain from voting since you said *This is fully verified by me and working great!!* (although I'm sure is not so)

Comment: @RaduRădeanu: that is why I mentioned to repeat the steps without un-mounting `/media/sdb1`. since `System Device Manager` is auto-mounting the drive `/media/sdb1` removes automatically when it `un-mounts`. You belief it or not! After this suggestion I was going to suggest the same thing or traditional file mounting way to [Cipricus](http://askubuntu.com/users/47206/cipricus). Any way thanks for your good and clear post.. :)

Answer (score 0):

One thing might be a problem here:
You cannot generally use

> /dev/sdb1

or

> /dev/sdc1

to assign permissions or ownership.

You need to use the name of the **mountpoint** (here /media/username) and change permissions and ownership there. So if your

> /dev

is

> /sdb1

and your mountpoint is

> /media/username/22a67f76

(here "username" is *your* username you are logged in with)

Your Stick will be mounted to a **similar** UUID.
Then the commands will look like this:
1)
You let the USB Stick automount as usual. (Plug it in) Check if it still mount to the same mountpoint. (just in case)
2)

> sudo chown -R username:users /media/username/22a67f76

annotations:
username = your username you are logged in with
users = group "users"
3)

> sudo chmod -R 777 /media/username/22a67f76

annotations:
username = your username you are logged in

with 777 = full access!!

Done! You now can directly write to this device!

Answer (score 0):

Updated for Ubuntu 21.04. The pre-built Disks Utility can load NTFS drives by default in read-write mode. However, for me the NTFS drive had an error created by Windows when it was last used, which was preventing it to open in write mode -

> The disk contains an unclean file system (0, 0).
> Metadata kept in Windows cache, refused to mount.
> Falling back to read-only mount because the NTFS partition is in an
> unsafe state. Please resume and shutdown Windows fully (no hibernation
> or fast restarting.)

So, I fixed this by first unmounting the drive from the Disks Utility and then performing the below to remove the error.

> `sudo ntfsfix /dev/sda3`

Then I mounted the drive again with the Disks Utility, and the drive opened in read-write mode.

Answer (score 0):

**Simplest fix for most windows formated disks**

My external drive was formated in windows and had this problem

i plugged in Ubuntu but didnt mount

```
sudo fdisk -l
```

And my disk was sdb, but since its not mounted it didnt show sdb1

but i did this command with sudo ntfsfix **/dev/sdb1** and then after it works when mounter. Look if its sda or sdb in fdisk command

```
sudo ntfsfix /dev/sda[ntfs_partion_number]
```